# How to decline a game invitation from friend

Tags: iphone, game-center

If I tap on the game invitation notification from a friend, the game is started.  It does not ask me to accept or decline. How do I decline a game invitation?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Game Center app and Decline the invitation:

[image]

Comment: After received the notification, I went to Game Center app.  But not sure what is the next step...